# Cannot bind some custom configurations in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a simple `HostedService` and I'm trying to read some strongly-typed configurations from an `appsettings.customs.json` file. Here is the app settings content:

```
{
  "ApproveSetting": {
    "CallCount": 1,
    "Sleep": "00:00:05"
  },
  "TrySetting": {
    "TryLifeTime": "03:00:00",
    "DelayTime": "00:00:30"
  }
}
```

I then add the `.json` file and bind the configurations as below:

```
public class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configuration) => {
                configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.customs.json", false, true);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                services.AddOptions();


                // tried both with and without the Bind(t) method
                services.Configure<ApproveSetting>(
                    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ApproveSetting"));

                // tried both with and without the Bind(t) method
                services.Configure<TrySetting>(t
                    => hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("TrySetting").Bind(t));
 
                // blah blah blah

            });
}
```

When I try to resolve the `Settings` in a service, I only get the `TrySetting`'s value, and the `ApproveSetting` is initialized by default values. It seems it only reads the `TrySetting`, and not the `ApproveSetting`.

As you can see, I've tried both `Configure(Secion)` and `Configure(t => ...Bind)` methods. Also I've tried to change the position on sections in `.json` file.

Have you any idea what's happening here?

**UPDATE:**

The `ApproveSetting` class:

```
public class ApproveSetting {

    public int CallCount { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Sleep { get; set; }

}
```

The `TrySetting` class:

```
public class TrySetting {
    public TimeSpan TryLifeTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan DelayTime { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2: The Answer:**

Finally I found the problem. The problem was that I had two `ApproveSetting` and `TrySetting` classes in two different namespaces. I was registering them with `namespace1` and was trying to resolve theme in `namespace2`. So, my bad.

Comment: how are you resolving it - what shape is the model classes?

Comment: Please, share `ApproveSetting` class

Comment: Check the file and filename for typos and also realize you don't have it mandatory flag (first boolean in the parameters IIRC). This means it won't error out on you and you think nothing is wrong.

If that doesn't work try Configruation.Get<ApproveSetting>("ApproveSetting"); just to make sure that it is deserializing correctly.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski see the updates please. Ive added classes.

Comment: @HouseCat Ill try these. Thanks to help.

Comment: Are we talking about the TimeSpan's not binding? Because I don't think as of official 3.1 release of NetCore we support JSON deserialization of TimeSpan out of the box. You would need to add a custom converter or a Nuget package.

Comment: @HouseCat But its binding in `TrySetting` successfully - and other services in application.